# Remove button after being clicked

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a page where the users can view their leave applications, I also have a Cancel button beside it which looks like this:

[View Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpXq0.png)

What I wanted to happen is that when I click on the cancel button, the status would change and the button would disappear.

I added a script that would make the button disappear and it worked, but it won't update the status.

So here's my form:

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
<h3>My Leaves</h3>
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
     <tr>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Reason</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Status</th>
     </tr>
    <?php
     include ('database.php');
     $result = $database->prepare ("SELECT leaves.* FROM leaves INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = leaves.user_id WHERE employee.username = '".$_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"]."'");
     $result ->execute();
     for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
    ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['firstname']." " .$row_message['lastname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['phone']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['email']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['fromdate']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['todate']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['reason']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['type']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['status']; ?></td>
      <td>
       <form method="post" action="update-leave-status-emp.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="leaveno" value="<?php echo $row_message['leaveno']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Cancelled" class="removebtn" name="cancelled"></input>
       </form>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
     
     </table>
     
     <a href="employee_panel.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Back</button></a> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

And here's the script below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".removebtn").click(function(){
   $(this).remove();
  });
 });
</script>
```

PHP Code:

```js
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['cancelled']))
    {
        $msg = "Cancelled";
        $status=$_POST['cancelled'];
    }
    $leaveno=$_POST['leaveno'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'companydb');

    $sql = "UPDATE leaves SET status = '$status' WHERE leaveno = '$leaveno'";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        header("refresh:1; url=view-leave-emp.php?msg=$msg");
    else
        var_dump(mysqli_error($con));
 
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? The button is removed, fine. What does "it won't update the status" mean? What should happen here?

Comment: @NicoHaase Everything works fine but the button wont disappear. So I added a script and now it wont update the database. The PHP code is fine.

Comment: @NicoHaase Without the remove button script, everything works fine. So how do I make the button disappear when I click on it at the same time it will update the database

Comment: So what you're saying is that the button gets removed but you're not being redirected to `update-leave-status-emp.php` nor any XHR is performed, therefore the PHP code is never executed. Right?

Comment: @Zeke Exactly! That's what I'm trying to say, sorry I wasn't able to explain it properly

Comment: Where's the code to execute any AJAX request? There's only code to remove a button, and maybe it is removed before the browser even triggers the form submission? Why do you want to remove the button anyways? The page will change on submitting the form and nobody will see that it is gone

Comment: I just wanted something new like when the users click cancel it will just cancel like they wouldn't be able to see the button anymore because its cancelled

Comment: @NicoHaase Zeke properly explained what is happening currently

Comment: Okay, so I don't know much about jQuery, to be honest, but I believe you can add an id to your form and do something like `$('#form-id').submit();` to force the submit event right after the button is removed. I don't know the reason why it's not being submitted since I can't see an `event.preventDefault();` line in your code, but you can give it a try. Maybe because the click method is being redefined in your script? I really don't know.

Comment: @Zeke I understand, i'll let you know afterwards. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I still am a little bit on @NicoHaase's side because, as he said, nobody will see the button once the database is updated... in any case, if it's due to an asynchronous behavior that you may add in the future (AJAX), then you could simply disable the button because in the event of a connection error, you will want to let the user have control of the button again... and recreating a button in JS is a pain afterwards. Anyway, you're welcome!

Comment: @AndreF Any updates?